# how to make sql statement to find siblings in a table

Tags: query, self-join

I have a question here which need your kindly help.
I have a table with the following data

```
family_id,student_Name
--------- ------------
A,Tom
B,Jack
C,Steve
B,Terry
C,Jerry
```

And then I want to write a SQL statement to obtain:

```
family_id,student_name,sibling_name
--------- ------------ ------------
A,tom,N/A
B,Jack,Terry
C,Steve,Jerry
B,Terry,Jack
C,Jerry,Steve
```

How to write this SQL statement?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: Any particular flavor of SQL you're using?

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! Note, these sites have an important entry requirement: you need to be able to explain your problem in round, clear sentences, containing all the required information. The required information your current text is missing: what exactly is the rule, how do you want to push these name together. Please, insert this info back. Good luck!

Comment: In particular, when we see questions like this (ones that at least *look* like a homework assignment), we generally expect you to provide your best attempt at a query to accomplish the job. There are also important questions - is it possible for there to be a third sibling? If so, how would that look? Also: is your example result above supposed to represent a result set with three separate columns (`family_id`,`student_name`, `sibling_name`), or a single column with comma-separated values)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's your test data:

```
insert into students values ('A','Tom');
insert into students values ('B','Jack');
insert into students values ('C','Steve');
insert into students values ('B','Terry');
insert into students values ('C','Jerry');
```

One way would be to use an outer join:

```
select 
    students.family_id, 
    students.student_name, 
    coalesce(siblings.student_name, 'N/A') as 'sibling'
from students 
left outer join  students as siblings 
  on students.family_id = siblings.family_id 
 and students.student_name != siblings.student_name;
```

Another would be to use a sub-select:

```
select 
    family_id,
    student_name,
    coalesce(
      ( select 
            min(student_name) 
        from students as siblings 
        where students.family_id = siblings.family_id 
          and students.student_name != siblings.student_name
      ),'N/A') as 'sibling'
from students;
```

You didn't define what you want to see if a family has three or more siblings. The first example will show a row for each sibling pair, and the second will just show one of a student's siblings.